# Celery can't connect to broker but executes scheduled tasks

Tags: heroku, celery, django-celery

We are using Celery 4.1.0 with Django 1.33.1 on Heroku. There are two dynos configured in the Procfile, one for web, one for both Celery worker and beat:

```
web: gunicorn dms.wsgi --log-file=-
worker: celery -A dms.tasks worker -B --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat
```

There are several scheduled tasks configured which execute just fine. However, when trying to send tasks to the broker it says `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`, seemingly regardless of the type of broker (Actually the process just times out and only shows the error when sending a task manually but we suspect this is related to a [different bug](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4296))

I tried [RabbitMQ](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudamqp) and [Redis](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis) and got the same error message on both. It is a staging environment with a single user and I double-checked we didn't hit any queue/connection limits.

`dms/settings.py`:

```
CELERY_BROKER = os.environ.get('CELERY_BROKER')
CELERY_TASK_IGNORE_RESULT = True
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
CELERY_IMPORTS = (
    'dms.tasks',
    'core.tasks',
)
```

`dms/tasks.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'dms.settings')

app = Celery('dms', broker=settings.CELERY_BROKER)
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

We also contacted Heroku and CloudAMQP support.